Neovim config custom mappings not working
I am using NvChad as my neovim config, and in the mappings.lua file I have defined a few custom mappings, which I am pretty sure are not conflicting with any other mappings, and yet they don't work:
i = {
    ["<C-s>"] = { "<cmd> w <CR>", "Save file" },
    ["<C-H>"] = {"<C-w>", "Delete a word"},
    ["<C-CR>"] = {"<ESC>o", "Enter a new line below"},
    ["<C-S-CR>"] = { "<ESC>S-o", "Enter a new line above" },
}

the above configs are custom made and are supposed to work when I am in the insert mode, out of these only the first one works, the rest don't work
I want Ctrl + Backspace to delete an entire word, Ctrl + Enter to enter a new line below the current line (just like in vscode) and Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter a new line above the current line
